# AngularJS Routing and Model - am I on the right track?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I just started out to convert our Application to AngularJS, and honestly... it's a pain in the ***. AngularJS is just soo different than good old plain Javascript!

I just wanted to make a app which shows a login-screen (data is fetched via AJAX) and after that shows an 'article info' page. Plain and simple - so I thought.

I made two html-pages, and made two modules. One module for the Users and one for the Articles. One page for the login and one page for the article info.

Both pages include the angular module, the routing module and my two modules:

```
<script src="angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="angular/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="modules/sachbearbeiter.js"></script>       
<script src="modules/artikelinfo.js"></script>
```

In the modules I did everything to get the routing right, relevant parts of the 'sachbearbeiter.js':

```
var sb = angular.module("sb", ['ngRoute']);

sb.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/login', {
            templateUrl: '/index.html',
            controller: 'sachbearbeiter'
        })  
        .when('/artinfo', {
            templateUrl: '/artinfo.html',
            controller: 'artikelinfo'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/login'
        });
});
```

Relevant parts of the 'artikelinfo.js':

```
var art = angular.module("art", ['sb, ngRoute']);

art.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/login', {
            templateUrl: '/index.html',
            controller: 'sachbearbeiter'
        })  
        .when('/artinfo', {
            templateUrl: '/artinfo.html',
            controller: 'artikelinfo'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/login'
        });
});
```

In the index.html I've defined my sachbearbeiter-module:

```
<div ng-app="sb" ng-controller="sachbearbeiter">
```

And after that I add a simple link and hoped that I could call my 'artinfo.html':

```
<a href="#/artinfo">Artikelinfo</a>
```

But it simple changes the URL Bar to:

```
SERVERNAME/artinfo//index.html#/artinfo
```

And nothing more happens. Even no Javascript Debug Output.

Am I on the right track by buildung a SinglePageApplication with two seperate .html-files, and two seperate .js-Files with all the controllers and factorys for one module (User/Sachbearbeiter and Artikelinfo/article info) ?

Getting the grasp around angularJS makes my Head Spin ...
All Examples I've found for NG-Routing do not use two different .js-Files and two different .html-Files.

Any Suggestions or help?

Greetings,
Thomas

Comment: try using `href="#artinfo"`

Comment: What does your url look like before you click the link?

Comment: After changing the link to "<a ng-href="/artinfo">Artikelinfo</a>", it simply reloades the page (because 'artinfo' ist also the part after the servername in the url). So before the click I have 'http://cd-dev-srv1/artinfo/" and after it also "http://cd-dev-srv1/artinfo/" because the page gets reloaded.

Comment: When using "<a ng-href="#/artinfo">Artikelinfo</a>", the URL changes to "http://cd-dev-srv1/artinfo/#/artinfo" after the click. But I stay on the login-page (index.html).

Answer (score 0):

So first thing I would say is good Angular is just good Javascript, so don't worry you will get there. Angular just takes a short time to adjust to. The best, and quickest, primer I can recommend is from Codecademy. It should only take a couple of hours to complete and you'll be damn glad you did it : 
https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-angularjs

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at [*ui-router*](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router), it is a better implementation of a router for Angular apps.

Anyways you are creatting two modules and adding the same routing to both of them. My aproach would be to have only one module handling the routing. And make other modules to handle other important parts of the app. But for small apps you can actually just have one module.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, thanks to you guys I think I've got it.
My main html-File (index.html) simple looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
        <title>Artikelinfo</title>

        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body>  

        <!-- Our main App, which includes all other modules -->
        <div ng-app="main" ng-view>
            <!-- Route-dependent content goes here -->
        </div>

        <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <!-- AngularJS -->
        <script src="angular/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="angular/angular-route.js"></script>
        <!-- Modules -->
        <script src="modules/routing.js"></script>
        <script src="modules/sachbearbeiter.js"></script>       
        <script src="modules/artikelinfo.js"></script>
        <script src="modules/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The main Module simple loads all moduls:

```
var main = angular.module("main", ['sb', 'art']);
```

And the routing module prepares the routes:

```
angular.module("", ['ngRoute'])
    .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/login', {
            templateUrl: '/artinfo/login.html',
        })  
        .when('/artinfo', {
            templateUrl: '/artinfo/artinfo.html',
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/login'
        });
    })
```

Now I have all modules loaded and simply can switch the view like this:

```
$location.path("/artinfo");
```

The only think I'm concerned about is the main-Module.
It seems that it has to load all Modules.
Will that make problems when there are hundreds or even thousands of them?

Thomas